# Applying a coupon to Woocommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce and need to apply a coupon to the cart automatically when the user has selected a checkbox. I have this code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'apply_coupon' );

function apply_coupon() {
$coupon_code = 'sale'; 

if ( WC()->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) ) return;
WC()->cart->apply_coupon( $coupon_code );
wc_print_notices();
}
```

But this adds the coupon ALL THE TIME. How can I add a checkbox and make the coupon only applied when the checkbox is selected?

Comment: It's possible that someone out there might write the application you need for you, for free. It wouldn't be an extremely complex task, but I think it still qualifies as a developer ask - add a checkbox to the cart (or checkout), apply a coupon using it, add needed messaging or other adjustments - rather than a stackoverflow question. If you want to do it yourself, you might begin by searching on how to add custom fields to WooCommerce checkout.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, i'm using the free plugin Yith WooCommerce Deals : https://yithemes.com/themes/plugins/yith-woocommerce-deals/

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to use another plugin. Also, the price of the products should not be reeuced, but a discount on the subtotal instead.